# Why when cleansession is enabled and set to true in Mosquitto.Conf Mosquitto Broker refuses to start?

Tags: mosquitto

I recently upgraded and updated my Mosquitto Broker to 1.4.15 on Raspberry-pi3. It works as expected. However, every time I enable and set **cleansession** to true in the **Mosquitto.Conf** file, Mosquitto broker refuses to start. As soon as I comment out or disable cleansession, Mosquitto broker starts up immediately by its service. The reason I need to set this to true is because I want the Mosquitto Broker to clean up any disconnected clients' session. So that the same client can reconnect again to the broker. Am I doing this right? or Is there another Mosquitto Broker's feature that I can use in place of **cleansession**?

Comment: Edit the question to include your `mosquitto.conf` and the log output when it fails to start. Also the `cleansession` flag in the `mosquitto.conf` file is only applicable to MQTT bridge connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cleansession` flag in the `mosquitto.conf` is to control what options mosquitto uses when it connects to remote brokers as a client when setting up a bridge.

If you want your clients to connect with a clean session then you need to set that option in your client library when setting up the connection not on the broker.

Comment: The library file I am using for Mosquitto Client in my project file doesn't have that option or designed as such anywhere in the library file.

Comment: Yes it does, all MQTT libraries have it as a connection option

Comment: I think you are right. It is not identified as option in the library. The author must be giving it a default value straight.

Comment: No, the default value is always false. https://mosquitto.org/man/libmosquitto-3.html#idm46613929624336

Comment: Yes. I meant the library doesn't specifically give the user option to choose true or false for this flag. After carefully analyzing the library file, I figured out that when the client goes to connect, it builds the packets bit by bit and one of the bit is CleanSession flag. Bit 2 is always set to 0x00=false.